# Accessing site via multiple virtual hosts with https

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, jira

I have an apache server that sits in front of a JIRA Service Desk instance running on Windows Server 2012.

We have 2 customer portals in JIRA and I need to set up Apache so that each customer portal can be accessed via a different virtual host.

Like this:

- Customer 1 accesses root like `it.mysite.com, or https://it.mysite.com` and gets 
  -- https://it.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1
- Customer 1 requests `/servicedesk/customer/portals` and gets
  -- https://it.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1
- any other request at all, like `it.mysite.com/somepage.html` should just get forced to SSL
- Customer 2 accesses root like `as.mysite.com, or https://as.mysite.com` and gets 
  -- https://as.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2
- Customer 2 requests `/servicedesk/customer/portals` and gets
  -- https://as.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2
- any other request at all, like `as.mysite.com/somepage.html` should just get forced to SSL

This is what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /servicedesk/customer/portal/1/ [R=301]
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
#Redirect permanent / https://www.it.mysite.com/  # tried this, it seemed to be ignored
ServerName www.it.mysite.com
ServerAlias it.mysite.com
....
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /servicedesk/customer/portal/2/ [R=301]
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
#Redirect permanent / https://www.as.mysite.com/  # tried this, it seemed to be ignored
ServerName www.as.mysite.com
ServerAlias as.mysite.com
....
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /servicedesk/customer/portal/1 [R=301] 
RewriteRule ^/servicedesk/customer/portals$ https://it.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1 [R=301] 
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
ServerName www.it.mysite.com
ServerAlias it.mysite.com
...
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /servicedesk/customer/portal/2 [R=301] 
RewriteRule ^/servicedesk/customer/portals$ https://as.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2 [R=301] 
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
ServerName www.as.mysite.com
ServerAlias as.mysite.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything seems to work as expected for it.mysite.com

However, if I go to as.mysite.com, I get:
`https://it.mysite.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2`

Https redirect works, the correct portal (2) is shown, but, the domain reverts to `it.mysite.com`

The same happens for any page I visit.
For example:
- `as.mysite.com/somepage.html` gets me `https://as.mysite.com/somepage.html`

Output for `C:\apache24\bin\httpd -S` is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.it.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:541)
         port 80 namevhost www.it.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:541)
                 alias it.mysite.com
         port 80 namevhost www.as.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:562)
                 alias as.mysite.com
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.it.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:596)
         port 443 namevhost www.it.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:596)
                 alias it.mysite.com
         port 443 namevhost www.as.mysite.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:636)
                 alias as.mysite.com
ServerRoot: "C:/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG

C:\Windows\system32>
```

**How can I make it keep the `as` subdomain?**

Comment: Although syntactically valid, using hostnames in <VirtualHost> tags is a bad idea. User *:port it IP:port (and dont mix the two unless you know what you are doing. I'd start by examining the output of "apachectl -S" and look for conflicting ServerNames/ServerAliases

Comment: @Unbeliever, I changed all the vhosts to be `*:port`. Im on windows, but I ran `httpd -k stop` then `httpd -k start`, no warnings displayed and no errors in the log but the issue persits.

Comment: DelightedD0D, can you show the output of "httpd -S" please?

Answer (score 0):

Your vhosts look fine. I would do the following to troubleshoot

1) Before each test, explicitly clear your browser cache, or use a command line tool such as curl to test the request

2) Add vhost specific access/error logs to each virtual host to make sure that the requests you are making are landing on the correct vhost

3) Enable the mod_rewrite logging to debug the rewrite. Details can be found here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog

Comment: Thanks, ill try this tonight when I can take the server out of production again